# Discord.py change channel title but keep id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

At the moment I have a ticket system with a confirmation command that moves the channel to another category. Tickets can be of two types "orders" and "estimates" and the titles are like "order-id" "estimate-id".

This is the confirmation command:

```
    if ctx.channel.name.startswith('order') or ctx.channel.name.startswith('estimate'):
        oldname = ctx.channel.name
        category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=config["confirm_category"])
        await ctx.channel.edit(name=f"{oldname}", category=category)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

This will verify the channel name if start with order or estimate but i would like that if the channel title starts with "estimate-id" to change into "order-id" and keep the actual id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) method to separate "estimate" and "id" like so:

```py
if ctx.channel.name.startswith('order') or ctx.channel.name.startswith('estimate'):
    cat, id = ctx.channel.name.split('-')
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=config["confirm_category"])
    await ctx.channel.edit(name=f"order-{id}", category=category)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```